# Getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm trying to perform Occlusion Analysis to understand what patches in my input image correlate maximally to the output of the model (last layer is the output of softmax). However, I keep getting the same error which says that the types are not matching I guess. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how to prevent the issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "occlusion.py", line 70, in <module>
    occlusion(attribute_extractor, jpegfile, mgn_output_for_original_img)
  File "occlusion.py", line 29, in occlusion
    output_height = int(np.ceil((height - int(occ_size)) / int(occ_stride)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

```
# model -> MGN - deep learning model
# image -> b_box cropped image of the person
# label -> MGN output label for the image


def occlusion(model, image, label, occ_size = 50, occ_stride = 50, occ_pixel = 0.5):

    #get the width and height of the img
    width, height = image.size, image.size
    print(width)
    print(height)

    #set the output img width and height
    output_height = int(np.ceil((height - int(occ_size)) / int(occ_stride)))
    output_width = int(np.ceil((width - int(occ_size)) / int(occ_stride)))

    #create a white image with the sizes defined above
    heatmap = torch.zeros((output_height, output_width))

    #iterate all the pixels in each column
    for h in range(0, height):
        for w in range(0, width):

            h_start = h*occ_stride
            w_start = w*occ_stride
            h_end = min(height, h_start + occ_size)
            w_end = min(width, w_start + occ_size)

            if (w_end) >= width or (h_end) >= height:
                continue

            input_image = image.clone().detach()

            #replacing all the pixel information in the image with occ_pixel(grey) in the specified location
            input_image[:, :, w_start:w_end, h_start:h_end] = occ_pixel

            #run inference on modified image
            output = model(input_image)
            output = nn.functional.softmax(output, dim=1)
            prob = output.tolist()[0][label]

            #setting the heatmap location to probability value
            heatmap[h, w] = prob

    return heatmap

attribute_extractor = MgnWrapper("./model.pt")
jpegfile = Image.open("tmpgal/    1.jpg")

width, height = jpegfile.size
print(type(width))
print(type(height))

mgn_output_for_original_img = attribute_extractor(jpegfile)
occlusion(attribute_extractor, jpegfile, mgn_output_for_original_img)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `width, height = image.size, image.size` be just `width, height = image.size` since image.size return a tuple of 2 elements which will be assigned to width and height respectively?

Comment: simply use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`) to see values in variables in this line - ie `print(height)` `print(type(height))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the assignment expression `width, height = image.size, image.size` to `width, height = image.size` since the original ones will make `width`'s and `height`'s values to be a tuple as `image.size` while the expression `width, height = image.size` will take the 2 elements inside the `image.size` tuple and assign each of the value to `width` and `height`

```
def occlusion(model, image, label, occ_size = 50, occ_stride = 50, occ_pixel = 0.5):

    #get the width and height of the img
    width, height = image.size
    print(width)
    print(height)

    #set the output img width and height
    output_height = int(np.ceil((height - int(occ_size)) / int(occ_stride)))
    output_width = int(np.ceil((width - int(occ_size)) / int(occ_stride)))

    #create a white image with the sizes defined above
    heatmap = torch.zeros((output_height, output_width))

    #iterate all the pixels in each column
    for h in range(0, height):
        for w in range(0, width):

            h_start = h*occ_stride
            w_start = w*occ_stride
            h_end = min(height, h_start + occ_size)
            w_end = min(width, w_start + occ_size)

            if (w_end) >= width or (h_end) >= height:
                continue

            input_image = image.clone().detach()

            #replacing all the pixel information in the image with occ_pixel(grey) in the specified location
            input_image[:, :, w_start:w_end, h_start:h_end] = occ_pixel

            #run inference on modified image
            output = model(input_image)
            output = nn.functional.softmax(output, dim=1)
            prob = output.tolist()[0][label]

            #setting the heatmap location to probability value
            heatmap[h, w] = prob

    return heatmap
```